# Filter log and send the ouput to a new file in real time

Tags: linux, bash, date, logging, centos

I have a log file "Apps.out" of an application for a WebLogic, there is a specific app that sends logs like this to that file:

```
[YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS][INFO][PATTERN -> Information1]
[YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS][INFO][PATTERN -> Information2]
[YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS][INFO][PATTERN -> Information3]
[YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS][INFO][PATTERN -> Information4]
[YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS][INFO][PATTERN -> Information5]
```

I can filter this information with: grep 'PATTERN' Apps.out
but I want to send this information to a new file (app1.log) and do this progressive just to send the new register on app1.log that matches the PATTERN, is it possible to do it in real-time?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `tail -f`:

`nohup bash -c "tail -f Apps.out | grep PATTERN > app1.log" &`

This will *follow* the file as it grows from the moment you start going back 10 lines.

You can change that with `-n` and go back as many lines as wish or read from the start of the file.

Comment: Hi there, one question, for this I need to have a terminal open all the time right?

Comment: You can use nohup to leave the terminal or a service of some kind

Comment: as you were first to answer edit your answer by adding nohup and I give you the upvote :)

Comment: fair enough :-). Done

Comment: Hi i got a error with the '>', I have tried but it is not working

Comment: Hi again, I think I found the mistake, with this is working very well: nohup bash -c "tail -f Apps.out | grep --line-buffered PATTERN > > app1.log" & this work nomaly even after close the console, thank you so much

Comment: @johsttincurahua `<PATTERN>` is to be replaced with your pattern, I'll edit the post as this notation may confuse others

Answer (score 0):

here is what you can do : `<your_log_file>` as your log file
and `<your_PATTERN>` as you PATTERN

```
nohup tail -f <your_log_file>.log|while IFS= read -r;do
    case $REPLY in
        (*<your_PATTERN>*)printf "%s\n" "$REPLY">>app1.log;
    esac
done &
```

Comment: Hi there this one looks that is working but I don't know why when I close the console it stops working after 2m